# regex:search character still not perfect

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str="KD-R35H2UND";
var patt1=/[G|T|EE|EJU].*D/i;
document.write(str.match(patt1));
</script>
```

by using code at `var patt1=...` i can show like this:

```
if i type KD-R35ED => SHOW ED
KD-R35UND => UND
KD-R35JD => JD
KD-R35TJD => TJD
KD-R35EED=> EED
```

my problem is: if i type `KD-R35GD` it can show `GD` but if `KD-R35D` it can't show anything..how to make it works?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the regex - especially this part `[EE|EJU]` - elaborate the input format and the matching criteria and post a couple of accepted and rejected strings.

Comment: @klox: that output is perfect for what the pattern is supposed to do. Clearly this is not what you want, so you need to tell the regex engine clearly what you want. If you can't do that, then you need to clearly tell us what you want, so we can tell you what to tell the engine what you clearly want. And that's clearly what I want.

Comment: stackoverflow:question still not perfect

Comment: @all: i'm already change my question,please check again

Comment: I assume all your input will not begin with KD-R35?  'cause if it does /KD-R35(.*)/ is the regex you want.  If it will not always begin with KD-R35 or if there will be trailing info, please post a description of the data format.

Comment: @beggs:i can't change KD-R35 Bcoz that is the default name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b*` means "match zero or more occurences of `b`".

`.` means "match any character except newline".

`[EE|EJU]` means "match an `E`, a `|`, a `J` or a `U`".

`.*` means "match any character except newline zero or more times".

`D` means "match a `D`".

So the regex is doing what you asked it to do.

From the examples you provided in your question, I'm guessing that the actual rules should be:

1. String starts with `KD-R35`.
2. Then any number of alphanumeric characters may follow, as long as
3. there is an `E`, a `J` or a `U` among them, and
4. the string ends in `D`.

These rules, as a regex, read:

```
^         # start of string
KD-R35    # literal text
(         # start of capturing group
  \w*     # any number of alphanumeric characters
  [EJU]   # at least one of E, J, or U
  \w*     # any number of alphanumeric characters
  D       # a D
)         # end of capturing group
$         # end of string
```

or, in JavaScript:

```
match = subject.match(/^KD-R35(\w*[EJU]\w*D)$/i);
if (match != null) {  // successful match
    mytext = match[1] // capturing group 1
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

I'm assuming that upper/lowercase don't matter.

EDIT: Erm, your new edit changes the rules. It seems that any string is allowed as long as it starts with `KD-R35` and ends in `D`. In this case, the regex would simply be `/^KD-R35(\w*D)$/i`.

Comment: I don't understand. `match[0]` contains the entire string ("KD-R35H2UND"), `match[1]` contains the variable part ("H2UND"). It is not possible to match only `H2UND` if it's preceded by `KD-R35` because JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind assertions.

Comment: after all can work i've been found another problem..please check at my question..

Answer (score 0):

Is the first part of the string (KD-R35) same (or at least the format) for all instances of the string you wish to validate?

Can you write a list of string examples and the extractions you would like have after regex match.

For example:

- KD-R35HASDF => HASDF
- KD-R35H1234 => H1234
- KD-R35HASDA => HASDA
- KD-R35HG54G => HG54G
- KD-R35HD23D => HD23D

If that is the case this regex might help:

> .{2}\-.{3}(.*)

Meaning:

1. any character 2 times
2. minus sign
3. any character 3 times
4. CAPTURE - any character any number of times

HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var str1="KD-R35HASDF";
        var str2="KD-R35H1234";
        var str3="KD-R35HASDA";
        var str4="KD-R35HG54G";
        var str5="KD-R35HD23D";
        var patt1=/.{2}\-.{3}(.*)/;
        document.write(str1.match(patt1)[1] + "<br>");
        document.write(str2.match(patt1)[1] + "<br>");
        document.write(str3.match(patt1)[1] + "<br>");
        document.write(str4.match(patt1)[1] + "<br>");
        document.write(str5.match(patt1)[1] + "<br>");
    </script>
```

And note that the str5.match(patt1) returns an array, so use the second element like this:

> str5.match(patt1)[1]

and you will get the result you are looking for

Comment: should be `.{2}-.{3}(.*)`, he wants everything after the `KD-R35` it seems.

Comment: it returns an array, you need to use
> str1.match(patt1)[1]

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str="KD-R35H2UND";
var patt1=/.{2}-.{3}(.*)/;
document.write(str.match(patt1));
</script>
```

I change to this one but show `KD-R35H2UND,H2UND`